# create a unique id for that is matched corresponding to the two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to create a column that generates a unique id that is matched with two of my columns in my data frame.

Here is below is the example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': [1, 2, 1, 3,4,5], 'brand': [76, 76, Arco, Shell, Arco, Cheveron],'address': [aa, aa, ab, bc, cd,de]})
```

I want a index that matches both the brand and address but not the month

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id':[1,1,2,3,4,5] 'month': [1, 2, 1, 3,4,5], 'brand': [76, 76, Arco, Shell, Arco, Cheveron],'address': [aa, aa, ab, bc, cd,de]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) with [`GroupBy.ngroup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

```
df.insert(0, 'id', df.groupby(['brand','address'], sort=False)['month'].ngroup() + 1)
print (df)
   id  month     brand address
0   1      1        76      aa
1   1      2        76      aa
2   2      1      Arco      ab
3   3      3     Shell      bc
4   4      4      Arco      cd
5   5      5  Cheveron      de
```

Or join columns together and use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
s = df['brand'].astype(str) + '-' + df['address'].astype(str)
df.insert(0, 'id', pd.factorize(s)[0] + 1)
```